# How to read the visual ID or human readable id printed on the smart card using HID OMNIKEY 5321 CL reader

Tags: python-3.x, mapping, smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader

I am using reader `HID OMNIKEY 5321 CL` to read the `Mifare DESFire card`. With the help of a python code given below, I am able to read unique identification number (UID). But I need to read the visual id printed on the card. The UID for my card is `04 11 64 FA BC 24 80` and the visual ID printed on card is `30307877`.

Python code by which I am able to read uid.

```
from smartcard.System import readers
from smartcard.util import toHexString
#Establish connection with the card reader
reader = readers()[0]
connection = reader.createConnection()
connection.connect()
#Transmit APDU command to retrieve data from the card
command = [0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]  # Change this command based on your specific needs
response, sw1, sw2 = connection.transmit(command)
#Print the response data
if sw1 == 0x90 and sw2 == 0x00:
    print("Data successfully read from the card:")
    print(toHexString(response))
else:
    print("Error reading data from the card.")
# Disconnect from the card reader
connection.disconnect()
```

Specifications of reader:

```
FW : 5.20
Op Mode : ISO
Lib : 200
Por: USB
USB Serial No :  OKCM007040812072942435634869263
ITEM NO : R53210038-1
REVISION : B
VERSION INDEX: ELZ00120
```

Mifare Desfire card specification:

```
Smartcard name: MiFare DESFire 
ATR : 3B 81 80 01 80 80
UID : 04 1A 68 FA BC 24 80
Protocol: ISO 14443A  T=CL
PICCtoPCD : 424 kbps
Frequency : 13.56 Mhz
PCDtoPICC
```

Can someone please provide me with the python code to read the visual ID or human readable id printed on my Desfire card?

I am able to get UID with the above python code. So, please provide me the python code to read visual id or human readable id printed on my desfire card.

Comment: I assume, this can't be answered without contacting the card issuer. The number needs not to be stored on the card at all but if it is, the storage location is arbitrary and may require a key to be read out.

Comment: I think you should contact the supplier and ask if this code is stored somewhere in the card so that you can find it through APDUs.

Comment: In a lot of cases the number printed on the card is calculated of the card's UID so that the printed number is as unique as the UID. As the UID ist a 7 bytes long array there are several ways to calculate a number of it and in the end: ask the supplier as mentioned by @MJay